# How to format oracle connection string and output query to file

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus, sql-loader, tnsnames

I am trying to connect to a oracle database, query it, and send results to a txt file. When I run my statement, this shows in the .txt file:

[image]

In reality, it should be values from my sql script.

Here is the string i am running:

```
sql_file1=Cb.sql

sqlplus -s "username/pwd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=my_host)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_ser_name))))" @sql/$sql_file1 > /home/path/to/my/files/'cb.txt'
```

Any reasons as to why my 'cb.txt' file shows the screenshot from above instead of any date from the query inside my sql file?

Answer (score 1):

You have extra `)` in your connection string:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=my_host)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_ser_name))))
```

should be

```
sqlplus -s "username/pwd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=my_host)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_ser_name)))" @sql/$sql_file1 > /home/path/to/my/files/cb.txt
```

But even easier to use EZConnect string:

```
sqlplus -s "username/pwd@//my_host:1521/my_ser_name" @sql/$sql_file1
```